# How to display hierarchical data structure with selectable Fluent UI DetailsList?

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have a nested data structure that looks like the following snippet:

```
[
  {
    id: "item1",
    children: [
      {
        id: "item1child1",
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: "item1child2",
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "item2",
    children: [
      {
        id: "item2child1",
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: "item2child2",
        children: [
          {
            id: "item2child2child1",
            children: [],
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is similar to a file structure, where a item in the array could have its own sub-array of children items, which also could have its own sub-array, and so on.

Using [Fluent UI's DetailsList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist), I want to be able to display this in a hierarchical structure, where sub-items are spaced further and further right. I was thinking of using a recursive approach as such (pseudocode):

```
RowComponent = ({item}) =>
  <Row item={item} />
  if (item.children.length > 0):
    for each (child in item.children):
        <RowComponent item={child} />
```

I have successfully implemented this basic view by using a custom `onRenderRow` function in the DetailsList. [You can view my implementation in this CodePen here](https://codepen.io/_wahoowa/pen/xxYBwaW?editors=0010). I am keeping track of the depth of call stack and using `style={{marginLeft: 40*level}}` to format the sub-items in the list.

[image: Nested list structure]

**However, I also want to add a multi-select functionality for each item in the list.** I have been playing around with the `ISelection` interface that gets passed through the `selection` prop of the DetailsList, but the problem is that upon selecting a single row in the list, it still selects the entire tree of items.

[image: Erroneous behavior]

When I click on the radio button for "item1child1", the items "item1" and "item1child2" also get selected. I would only like to select the one that I clicked on. I would also like to support selecting multiple rows. How can I do this using the DetailsList?

Comment: [Here is a CodePen of more of a "hack" than a solution](https://codepen.io/_wahoowa/pen/JjBQpRK?editors=0010). I'd imagine another solution is to flatten out the array and treat each nested item as its own item. Then, use the `onRender` property of a column to properly space out the column name, based on the depth of the item.